# HttpURLConnection not allowing me to post when I have https:// in the URL

Tags: android, ssl, post, https, httpurlconnection

How can I get POST request to work with an "https:" url?

In the following example when I set the URL to "https" instead of "http" the HttpURLConnection automatically makes my request a "GET" ?! while when it was a regular http request it was a POST...

```
    URL url = new URL("*https:*//www.google.com");
   // URL url = new URL("*http:*//www.google.com");

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        //writeStream(out);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        // readStream(in);
    }finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBADj.png)

Comment: Have you tried out other url's than www.google.com? Google has some restricted rules

Comment: Yes, I've tried many different urls including the one I'm building for the client. I just couldn't use that one in the example for security reasons. When using org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost everything worked fine. As soon as I tried to migrate to using HttpURLConnection I could no longer POST.

Comment: It looks like a security issue. For https, you need to use some certification/authentication which is supported by server and then only it can post the data to server. I may be wrong.

Comment: Did you try being more explicit about POST by saying `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");`?

Comment: Yes I've done everything by the book.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`